# how to call javascript functions from parent page?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I got a page which has an iframe. This page has a masterpage on which there is a js function defined.

masterpage contains:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/somejs.js"></script>
```

page with iframe:

```
  <div >
    <iframe id="myIframe" runat="server"></iframe>
  </div>
```

how can i call functions in the 'somejs.js' file?

Answer (score 1):

If both documents are from the same domain, you can simply call like

```
window.parent.someFunction();
```

Otherwise it's the whole different story.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite clear.

You have a `page.master` which has `<script type="text/javascript" src="/somejs.js"></script>`

Then a `default.aspx` with

```
<div >
    <iframe id="myIframe" runat="server"></iframe>
</div>
```

In your `iframe`, i think you want to show some other page.

So, if you want ur javascript outside `iframe`,

you can just call it normally like `onload=function1();`

Coz when default.aspx is converted to html, it takes everything from master page including ur declaration for javascripts..

Another way is that you can call it from codebehind `.cs` file.

Eg,

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude("selective", ResolveUrl(@"js\common.js"));
        if (!Master.Page.ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered("alert"))
        {
            Master.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript
                (this.GetType(), "alert", "initHomeTabsLoad();", true);
        }
```

But if you want ur javascript inside ifram, it's another story as you need to call that script on that original page.

Comment: what do you want ur javascript to do?